# Find bases so that Transformation matrix is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Find bases $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $w_1,w_2$ in $R^2$ relative to which the matrix of $T$ = $ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right)$ is in diagonal form.

Ans: $e_1 = j, e_2 = k, e_3 = i$, $w_1 = (1,1)$, $w_2 = (1,-1)$

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write $T$ in a diagonal form one has to find a basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$
and a basis $(w_1, w_2)$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ such that
$$ Te_1=w_1, \quad Te_2=w_2, \quad \text{and}\quad Te_3=0. \tag1$$
(This is possible because $T$ has rank $2$ which is the dimension of the second space.)
Let $(i,j,k)$ be the standard basis in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and $(i,j)$ the standard basis in ${\mathbb R}^2$. Observe that
$$ T i=0,\quad Tj=i+j, \quad \text{and}\quad Tk=i-j. $$
Since $w_1=i+j$ and $w_2=i-j$ are linearly independent they form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$.
Hence if one set $e_1=j, e_2=k, e_3=0$, then we have (1).

Note that the above linear form is not unique, conditions in (1) can be replaced by
$$ Tf_1=\lambda u_1, \quad Tf_2=\mu u_2, \quad \text{and}\quad Tf_3=0 $$
where $\lambda, \mu$ are nonzero numbers and  $(f_1, f_2, f_3)$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$ and  $(u_1, u_2)$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$.

**Explanation**

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over ${\mathbb R}$, $\dim(V)=m$ and $\dim(W)=n$, and let
$T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation (which means that for arbitrary $v_1, v_2 \in V$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in {\mathbb R}$ one has $T(\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2)=\alpha_1 Tv_1+\alpha_2 Tv_2$). If $(e_1, \ldots, e_m)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ is
a basis of $W$, then $T$ can be represented by an $n\times m$ matrix as  follows. Let $j\in \{ 1, \ldots, m\}$ and consider vector $Te_j$. It is a vector in $W$ and therefore can be uniquely represented as
$$ Te_j=t_{1j}f_1+\cdots+t_{nj}f_j $$
because $(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ is a basis of $W$.
Numbers $t_{1j}, \ldots t_{nj}$ form the $j$-th column of the matrix which represents $T$ with respect to the bases $(e_1, \ldots, e_m)$ and $(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$. Hence, the whole matrix is
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
t_{11} & t_{12} & \cdots & t_{1m}\\
t_{21} & t_{22} & \cdots & t_{2m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t_{n1} & t_{n2} & \cdots & t_{nm}
\end{array} \right]. $$
If one represents $v=\lambda_1 e_1+\cdots+\lambda_m e_m$ as a column vector
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} \lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \vdots\\ \lambda_m\end{array}\right], $$
then
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
t_{11} & t_{12} & \cdots & t_{1m}\\
t_{21} & t_{22} & \cdots & t_{2m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
t_{n1} & t_{n2} & \cdots & t_{nm}
\end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{c} \lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \vdots\\ \lambda_m\end{array}\right]=
\left[ \begin{array}{c} t_{11}\lambda_1+t_{12}\lambda_2+\cdots+t_{1m}\lambda_m\\ t_{21}\lambda_1+t_{22}\lambda_2+\cdots+t_{2m}\lambda_m\\ \vdots\\ t_{n1}\lambda_1+t_{n2}\lambda_2+\cdots+t_{nm}\lambda_m\end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c} \mu_1\\ \mu_2\\ \vdots\\ \mu_n\end{array}\right], $$
where $\mu_1, \cdots, \mu_n$ are the coefficients in the expansion of vector $Tv$ in basis $(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, i.e.,
$$ Tv=\mu_1 f_1+\cdots+\mu_n f_n.$$

In the case of the vector space ${\mathbb R}^k$ one has a natural basis, called the standard basis:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{array} \right],\quad \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1\\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{array} \right],\quad \ldots, \quad
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{array} \right]. $$
If an $n\times m$ matrix is given, then one considers it as a matrix which represents a linear transformation from ${\mathbb R}^m$ to ${\mathbb R}^n$ with respect to the standard bases in ${\mathbb R}^m$, resp. in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

In the case above one has $m=3$ and $n=2$. The standard bases are usualy denoted as
$$ i=\left[ \begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right], \quad j=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{array}\right], \quad k=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right]\quad \text{in}\quad {\mathbb R}^3$$ 
and
$$ i=\left[ \begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right], \quad j=\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\ 1\end{array}\right]\quad \text{in}\quad {\mathbb R}^2.$$ 
We have a matrix
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & -1\end{array}\right] $$
which represents a linear transformation $T:{\mathbb R}^3 \to {\mathbb R}^2$ with respect to the standard bases $(i,j,k)$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and $(i,j)$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$. The question is to find such bases $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and $(w_1, w_2)$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ that $T$ will be represented by a diagonal matrix with respect to these bases. It means that the bases have to be chosen in a way that one has
$$ Te_1=\lambda w_1,\quad Te_2=\mu w_2,\quad Te_3=0 $$
for some numbers $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Since $T$ is surjective $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are non-zero. Also one can assume that $\lambda=\mu =1$ (if there was an additional condition that the bases have to consist of vectors with norm $1$, then we couldn't assume that those numbers are $1$ but we would calculate them - however in our case there is no condition about norms, so we can assume that those numbers are $1$). Hence we would like to have
$$ Te_1=w_1,\quad Te_2=w_2,\quad Te_3=0. \tag2$$
Now we observe that
$$ T i=0,\quad Tj=i+j, \quad \text{and}\quad Tk=i-j. $$
Hence if we choose new bases as follows:

$e_1=j,\quad e_2=k,\quad e_3=0\quad$ the new basis in ${\mathbb R}^3$
and

$w_1=i+j, \quad w_2=i-j\quad$ the new basis in ${\mathbb R}^2$,

then (2) is fulfilled. Hence with respect to these new bases $T$ is represented by the matrix
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]. $$
It means, if we expand $v\in {\mathbb R}^3$ with respect to the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ as
$$ v=\alpha_1 e_1+\alpha_2 e_2+\alpha_3 e_2, $$
then $Tv$, which is a vector in ${\mathbb R}^2$, will have an expansion
$$ Tv=\alpha_1 w_1+\alpha_2 w_2 $$
with respect to the basis $(w_1,w_2)$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{array}\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{array}\right]. $$
$\left[ \begin{array}{c} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{array}\right]$ is the column of $v$ with respect to the basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{c} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{array}\right]$ is the column of $Tv$ with respect to the basis $(w_1,w_2)$.

Comment: Where do we show that $T$ must be diagonal?

Comment: In new bases $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and $(w_1,w_2)$ one has $Te_1=w_1$, $Te_2=w_2$, $Te_3=0$, which means that $T$ has form $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: Actually one should distinguish between  **matrix** and **linear transformation**. In your question $T$ is a matrix which represents a linear transformation $\tau$ with respect to the standard bases. Now we have chosen new bases such that $\tau$ is represented by a diagonal matrix.

Comment: If $T$ has the form $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$, then why does $Te_1 \neq w_1$?

Comment: Be careful! In the new bases also vectors are represented by different matrices (columns) as before. For instance, with respect to the basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ vector $e_1$ is represented by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Similarly, with respect to $(w_1,w_2)$ vector $w_1$ is represented by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Hence one has $Te_1=w_1$ if $T$, $e_1$ and $w_1$ are represented by matrices in new bases.